# Finding string(s) from the list of strings having no vowel in it

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice

I tried creating a program which finds out the string(s) from the list of strings which doesn't have a vowel in it. For what test case(s) this program would fail to execute successfully if there are any also the solutions to that would be useful

```
def contain(str,set):
    return 1 in[c in str for c in set]
def find_Novowels(inp_str):
    op="aeiouAEIOU"
    out=[]
    for i in inp_str:
        if contain(i,op):
            continue
        else:
            out.append(i)
    return(out)

 
#Main section.  
if __name__=='__main__':
        count=int(input())
        inp_str=[]
        for i in range(count):
                inp_str.append(input())
        output=find_Novowels(inp_str)
        if len(output)!=0:
                print('Strings without vowels:')
                for i in output:
                        print(i,end="")
        else:
                print('No string found')
```

Comment: it works fine for me it gives all sentences which doesn't contains vowels

Comment: On a coding platform it isn't executing successfully two of its private test cases are failing @Bhupeshlad